# Inserting and reading multiple values within nested list

Tags: python

I have this piece of code

```
def get_vector (vx,vy):
    lst = [[[] for _ in range (len(vx[0]))]for _ in range (len(vx))]
    print (lst[1])
    for x in range (len(lst)):
        for y in range (len(lst[x])):
            print (vx[x,y])
            c = math.sqrt(pow(vx[x,y],2)+pow(vy[x,y],2))
            print (c)
            cos_angle_y= ((pow(vx[x,y],2)) + (pow(c,2)) - (pow(vy[x,y],2))) / 2*vx[x,y]*c
            uhol=math.cos(math.radians(cos_angle_y))
            lst[x][y].append([c,uhol])
    return lst
```

my question is how can i acces or save those values so i can access them later from nested list. i tried this but it kinda work but not really. I get the right values but i'm not sure how to access them.

```
lst = get_vector(vx,vy)
print (lst[0][10])
```

this is the result I get from print `lst[0][10] : [[1.0, 0.9998476951563913]]`

I need to get value 0.999... to another variable outside of the list within the structure similar to lst[0][10][2] or some different approach if possible, any advice ?

Comment: seem like the right answer to the problem i had was to index it lst[0][10][0][1] tho i would like to get it down to 3 indexes .... any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so first mistake I made was indexing as mentioned in a post above although the indexing was not lst[0][10][1] but lst[0][10][0][1]. I've also resolved the issue with append creating extra index by changing append to insert and splitting the insertion into two separate steps like so

```
 lst[x][y].insert(0,c)
 lst[x][y].insert(1,uhol)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a third index position to access the values.

var = lst[0][10][1]

And so on to access individual values within nested lists. Remember that indexing starts from zero, so the second element is index 1

Comment: i've tried that method and i get  :   "IndexError: list index out of range" with values lst[0][10][1]